# find widest column width in excel workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel workbook with ~ 150 sheets.
Is there a way to find the widest column (in this case Column C) and then set  Column "C" in each sheet the workbook to this width?
thanks in advance
Chaz

Comment: Yes there is a way.  What have you tried?

Comment: Hey Thomas, I have only manually went through each tab and checked each width of Col "C". i don't know how to do it automatically, thus the reason for the question

Comment: You should always try and post some code with the your question.  Do you want the the widest column auto fit to it's actual width or just use it's current ColumnWidth?

Comment: Hi Thomas. I have done a bit of a work around.                                                Sub C_Merge_To_Master()
' Combines all sheets to a Master sheet
    Dim J As Integer
     On Error Resume Next
    Sheets(2).Select
    Sheets(2).Name = "Sheets Combined" 
    For J = 3 To Sheets.Count 
        Sheets(J).Activate 
        Range("A2").Select
        Selection.CurrentRegion.Select        
        Selection.Offset(1, 0).Resize(Selection.Rows.Count - 1).Select      
        Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(2).Range("A130000").End(xlUp)(2)         
    Next
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Main
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim maxWidth As Long
    Dim sht As Worksheet

    For Each sht in Worksheets
        For Each cell In sht.UsedRange.Rows(1)
            If cell.Width > maxWidth Then maxWidth = cell.Width
        Next cell
    Next sht

    For Each sht in Worksheets
        sht.Columns("C").ColumnWidth = maxWidth
    Next sht
 End Sub
```

Comment: @Chaz, did you get through it?

Comment: @ User3598756 I ended up merging the sheets together to get what i needed done. Cheers